# Auto Start/Stop of Programs

Tags: windows-10, task-scheduler, application-launch

I want a windows application to start and run for 5 minutes and then stop and then again suddenly start and repeat the whole process again. But I don't know how to do it in Windows Scheduler or by batch files. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one basic batch file solution you can adjust to meet your needs:

```
:s
start charmap
timeout /t 300
taskkill /F /IM charmap.exe
goto s
```

Comment: how can I start application minimized?

Comment: If you're using start.exe, you can pass in the /MIN switch as listed in the help, i.e. `start /?`.  In the above example, the line would be: `start /MIN charmap`

Comment: Glad it helped. Some applications have a more graceful way to close them rather than killing them externally but If it works then that’s fine. The only concern with killing the process is that it may not have time to persist state/config etc..